# Rephrase: "To fix this,..."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

(In technical writing)

I often find myself describing a problem over the course of a few sentences or paragraphs, then starting the next sentence with something to the effect, "To fix this..." or "In remedy..."

But this is awkward wording. Is there a better way of saying this?

Comment: By saying "is there a better conjunctive adverb for this?", you are implying that the expressions "to fix this" and "in remedy" are themselves 'conjunctive adverbs. Can you explain your rationale for thinking this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I implied. I guess this is wrong? I tried to find the best description of these words which are used to start a sentence, and link it to a previous thought. I edited the question (removing references to "conjunctive adverbs" to simplify it)

Comment: Alternatively, addressing your question with the word 'addressing' might be an option.

Comment: "solving the problem", "solves the problem" or "The/one/our solution" are other similar approaches. ('cure', 'removes', 'restores' etc are possible others).. there are almost too many for an answer...

Comment: I set up such scenarios with labels: Issue or Challenge (one or more paragraphs) and Solution (one or more paragraphs).

Comment: My model is **1. Executive Summary** stating the recommendation (i.e. the answer). **2. Problem statement** just the facts, no history. **3. Impact of doing nothing** why exert effort if the situation is no worse in a year?. **4. Alternatives considered but rejected** with pros & cons. **5. Recommended solution** with pros, cons and risk containment for the cons. **6. Next steps** here is how you implement the recommendation.

Comment: Solution: simply start a paragraph with the word "Solution:"...it may not be 100% grammatical, but it's clear and concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the perspective of someone who *uses* technical documentation, **your wording is fine**.  It may seem awkward to you as a *writer*, but for the reader in search of usable information, simple and consistent phrasing is a big help.

If you can consistently summarize a problem in a few sentences, and transition to a clear solution with a simple "To fix this", you're already in the top 10% of technical writers.

Comment: +1 for noting that saying "to fix this" or similar is a valid introduction to a solution.